# What’s this diagonal metal strapping between my studs?

Tags: drywall, walls, insulation, wood

So I’m trying to install a pet door and came across this between my studs. This is the second pet door I install and have never seen this. I’m in the dinning room and the wall is obviously an outside wall. Can I just snip it off? Or should I relocate?

[image: Angled steel between studs]

Comment: looks like it is a discarded item ... you do not say if it is loose

Comment: If it's loose, pull it out. If it's firmly attached, it may be some sort of wind sheer bracing. How close to a corner is this? Where in the world are you located - do you get hurricanes or earthquakes? What's on the other side of that black tar paper - if it's solid wood, the bracing may not be necessary, if it's just insulating foam, it might be.

Comment: Looks like an extruded aluminum track of some kind running at an angle.  Curious.  Perhaps shear support ? Looks like carpet transition tack strip at first glance.

Comment: It goes through the stubs partially and there is foam behind the black layer. I’m in Arizona.

Comment: Maybe some kind of support for the "foam". You could frame the opening with 2x4 and then attach the track to the framing. ??

Comment: If your wall sheathing is just foam this is probably diagonal (shear) bracing, as Alaska Man suggested. If that's the case, it's unlikely to be a problem until it is. :P

Comment: Looks a little like wind bracing to me.  Especially if the insulation is in front of it.  Is the home in an occasionally high-wind area (aka hurricanes, etc)?

Comment: STOP - DO NOT CUT - Its shear bracing for walls built with foam sheathing, instead of more rigid materials like OSB, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, that should not be cut. It appears to be a structural part of the house. There will be others like that in the wall, at least 1 more, and if the wall is over 20' it will most likely have an extra one, 3 total. That was code minimum back in the day, and probably still is.

There is a chance that nothing would ever happen bad if it was cut, but that chance, I cannot recommend removing it. Code guidelines are the minimum, never advisable to do something that reduces the effectiveness of a building component that is structural in nature.